# Runtime Error in asp.net?(online )

Tags: asp.net

I develop   a web application it is working fine in local. 
When i upload the site in online through CuteFTP it is showing the error like this...

> Description: An application error
>   occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this
>   application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed
>   remotely (for security reasons). It
>   could, however, be viewed by browsers
>   running on the local server machine. 
>        Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please
>   create a  tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

please help me i place the  but even though it is not working it is giving same error. Thank you

Comment: Is this coding problem or any network problem

Comment: Now it is showing this error
ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

Comment: This doesn't tell you what the real error is. change the customErrors mode to "Off" instead of "RemoteOnly".

Comment: Now i am getting this error
ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create a custom errors section in your web.config? See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(VS.71).aspx

As the error message says you need to set this to "Off" to see errors remotely.

You could also look at the event logs on the server for clues.

If you have remote desktop access to the server you can try logging on there and connecting to localhost and see what that tells you.

Comment: This is almost certainly an error in your application but you won't see it unless you follow the sugestions above. By default ASP.Net will not show errors in the browser unless you alter the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

The message says "something happened but I am not allowed to show the error. Do this to see the error". So make those changes and try again.

EDIT
Your answer to your question (by the way: it would be clearer to edit the question itself) suggests that you want to write to some directory. On your development system, that worked because then the webapp ran under your own account. On the server the webapp runs under the specified accounts.

So: find the directory where you want to write to, and give the correct account "write" rights there.

Comment: but i am not understand what is the problem, this is the url m3connect.in can u check Mr. Hans Kesting

Comment: The error can be anything, the real error is not in the message you showed. Try changing the web.config (on the server) as specified in the errormessage and maybe check with a browser on the server (so you can access the site through "localhost"). THEN you will see the real error.

Answer (score 0):

"Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"."

Try this and check what the error is.

If you can't, run the application from the server (using a remote desktop tool)..

If you can't, add a try catch that writes the exception to a text file.

Comment: Don't really know... the message you are getting is "you have a problem but i don't have permission to show it to you". This 3 steps will help you find out the real problem.